# No class def found error weka/core/attributes caused by classnotfoundexception weka.core.attribute

Tags: java, eclipse, weka, dtn

I'm trying a machine learning routing algorithm for DTN networks. I'm using weka and the ONE simulator. I'm running across this error when I'm trying to run my implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had `weka.jar` classpath issue. Used the following command to run the application.

```
java -Xmx512M -cp .;lib/ECLA.jar;lib/DTNConsoleConnection.jar;lib/weka.jar core.DTNSim %*
```